Tabulator rowClick does not work when editable:false is set to all columns
I have a tabulator 6.2.1 table where all columns are initially set editable:false. I want to make it so that when a row is clicked it becomes selected and when the row is double-clicked it becomes editable.
When I clicked or double-clicked on a row nothing happens.
It seems that tabulator blocks the cellClick, rowClick and rowDblClick events when all columns are set to editable:false.
To set all visible columns as editable, I use a function called setRowEditable(row, editable) that loops through all cells in a row and if the cell is visible and has a field it modifies its definition by changing editable option to the value of editable parameter (true or false).
This is the code:
        // Function to set row editable or not.
        function setRowEditable(row, editable) {
            row.getCells().forEach(function (cell) {
                let col = cell.getColumn();
                if (col.isVisible() && col.getField()) {
                    col.updateDefinition({ editable: editable });
                }
            });
            row.getTable().redraw(); // I make sure the changes are applied visually.
        }

        // Sample Data
        var tableData = [
            { id: 1, name: "John Doe", age: 28, gender: "Male" },
            { id: 2, name: "Jane Smith", age: 32, gender: "Female" },
            { id: 3, name: "Billy Bob", age: 44, gender: "Male" },
        ];

        // Table setup
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
            data: tableData, // Datos para la tabla
            layout: "fitColumns", // Ajuste automático de columnas
            columns: [
                {
                    headerSort: false, frozen: true, width:30, minWidth: 30,
                    formatter: function (cell) {
                        let el = cell.getElement();
                        el.style.backgroundColor = "#E0DFE3";
                    }
                },
                { title: "ID", field: "id", editable: false },
                { title: "Name", field: "name", editable: false },
                { title: "Age", field: "age", editable: false },
                { title: "Gender", field: "gender", editable: false },
            ],
            rowClick: function (e, row) {
                console.log('rowClick');
                row.selected();
            },
            rowDblClick: function (e, row) {
                console.log('rowDblClick');
                row.selected();
                setRowEditable(row, true);
            },
        });


Something changed after version 5.5 that caused this behavior. I'm currently on version 5.5 and I can still select a row even if a column has editable:false. I tried switching to a new version recently but it broke my row selection behavior (even after updating to the new row selection syntax). I'm not sure if this a bug or intended behavior of the editable property now.
